# How to make my red circle always stays on the green line using html and css code?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a webpage like this:

[image]

Its code can be found [here in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5ze2ud39/5/)

```
<div class="arrow">
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="triangle"></div>
</div>

<div id="warmup_container">
  <p id="warmup_title">這是中文</p>
  <div id="warmup_mark"></div>
  <p id="warmup_text">some text </p>
</div>
```

```
:root {
  --arrow-body-length: 500px;
  --arrow-tip-length: 30px;
}
.arrow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 42%;
  width: var(--arrow-body-length) + var(--arrow-tip-length);
}

.line {
  margin-top: 11px;
  width: var(--arrow-body-length);
  background: green;
  height: 9px;
  float: left;
}

.triangle {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 15px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
  border-left: var(--arrow-tip-length) solid green;
  float: right;
}

#warmup_container {
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 8%;
}
#warmup_title {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0px;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
}

#warmup_mark {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: -10px;
}

#warmup_text {
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
}
```

My problem is that when I add more characters into `warmup_title`, the red circle would not stay on the green line.

[image]

How can I change my code so that the red circle always stays on the green line no matter how many characters I type in `warmup_title` element?

The red circle might also not stay on the green line when I change the size of the window of my browser.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```css
:root {
  --arrow-body-length: 500px;
  --arrow-tip-length: 30px;
}
.arrow {
  display: inline-flex;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 40%;
  width: var(--arrow-body-length) + var(--arrow-tip-length);
}

.line {
  margin-top: 11px;
  width: var(--arrow-body-length);
  background: green;
  height: 9px;
  float: left;
}

.triangle {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 15px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
  border-left: var(--arrow-tip-length) solid green;
  float: right;
}

#warmup_container {
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 8%;
}
#warmup_title {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0px;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
}

#warmup_mark {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: -10px;
  z-index: 10;
}

#warmup_text {
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="warmup_container">
  <p id="warmup_title">這是中文abc</p>
  <div id="warmup_mark"></div>
  <p id="warmup_text">some text </p>
  <div class="arrow">
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="triangle"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your idea of fixing the green line is right, but it shouldn't use the `top` property, since the text can be extend, so it will break the visual. Instead make it `bottom` to anchor it at the end; also remove the `height: 200px`, add an outer div with `position: relative` to contain the absolute one.

About the breaking arrow when changing window size, i think make it `width: 100%` with a `max-width` to contain the width of it done better job than fixing it right away, so it can responsive with the screen size.

```css
:root {
  --arrow-body-length: calc(100% - 30px);
  --arrow-tip-length: 30px;
}
.container {
    position: relative;
}
.arrow {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 35px;
  width: var(--arrow-body-length) + var(--arrow-tip-length);
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
}

.line {
  margin-top: 11px;
  width: var(--arrow-body-length);
  background: green;
  height: 9px;
  float: left;
}

.triangle {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 15px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
  border-left: var(--arrow-tip-length) solid green;
  float: right;
}

#warmup_container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}
#warmup_title {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0px;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
}

#warmup_mark {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: -10px;
}

#warmup_text {
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="arrow">
        <div class="line"></div>
        <div class="triangle"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="warmup_container">
        <p id="warmup_title">這是中文abc def</p>
        <div id="warmup_mark"></div>
        <p id="warmup_text">some text </p>
    </div>
</div>
```